# Does Ethereum has halving or anything equivalent?

Tags: proof-of-stake, proof-of-work, protocol, block-reward

Bitcoin has a halving which will likely happen around June 2020. Is there anything similar for Ethereum? If not, why?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5913/how-does-the-ethereum-homestead-difficulty-adjustment-algorithm-work

Comment: There is a planned migration away from proof-of-work that will change the mining process. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9/why-does-ethereum-plan-to-move-to-proof-of-stake

Comment: Meanwhile, there is the _difficulty bomb_. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3819/87