# Parity: what is "bombDefuseTransition"

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, difficulty-bomb

I see the Parity option for "bombDefuseTransition" here, under chain spec:

https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Chain-specification

Two questions:

1 - Why is this needed?  (Would I be correct in saying that the difficulty bomb is coded into the software, therefore ANY test/dev net you use will have it, *unless* you use that flag?)

2 - How would one know what "block number at which the difficulty bomb (epsilon in Yellow Paper Eqs. 39, 44)" should be removed at?

Answer (score 3):

Only a partial answer, and it might require someone who knows about Ethereum Classic (i.e. the ETC chain) to confirm...

This option was added during the addition of support for the Expanse network (EXP), under Parity issue [#2369](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/pull/2369). However, I believe it's probably actually related to [ECIP-1010](https://github.com/ethereumproject/ECIPs/blob/master/ECIPs/ECIP-1010.md), which is Ethereum Classic's (mainnet) delay of the [Difficulty Bomb](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/323/what-is-the-difficulty-bomb-and-what-is-the-goal-of-it).

For the only relevant block of code - i.e. the code that uses `bomb_defuse_transition` (i.e. `bombDefuseTransition`), and handles ECIP-1010 - see [`ethash.rs`](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/35958a09658d0aec37200ca2881970cb7ac7f7e3/ethcore/src/ethereum/ethash.rs#L473).

So really this is a test option that allows Ethereum Classic test networks to simulate the Difficulty Bomb changes in ECIP-1010. (I *think*.)

**Edit (9th May 2017):**

As per [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/16007/52) answer to a follow-up question, it looks like setting the `bombDefuseTransition` option in the genesis file *will* deactivate the Difficulty Bomb, as you suspect. So, while it was added for Expanse support, it's a general option that will work with any private chain.

Comment: So if operating on a custom (public but non-standard) chain, is there any way to diffuse the difficulty bomb and continue operating as though Ice Age doesn't exist?