# Is there any way to diffuse the difficulty bomb and continue operating as though Ice Age doesn't exist?

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, difficulty-bomb

I am running a private chain for my own purposes.  Rather: it's a "public" discoverable chain but not any known or publicized chain.

I want to continue to run this with PoW and no difficulty bomb.  Is this possible?  I had though I could do it with one flag in Parity, but [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15904/parity-what-is-bombdefusetransition/15919#15919) suggests maybe not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can *defuse* the bomb by adding the `defuseBombTransition` parameter to the ethash parameters in the chain spec json, like this:

```
"bombDefuseTransition": "0x539",
```

The lower the value, the earlier the bomb is disabled. You can see this parameter in action for the [expanse network](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/b50fb71dd1d29dfde2a6c7e1830447cf30896c31/ethcore/res/ethereum/expanse.json#L17).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I'll edit my answer to the referenced question to make it correct. :-)

Comment: Thanks!  What encoding is that number in, and how would I determine what block to de-fuse (makes sense) at?  I'm thinking that for a dev/private network, I would just use 0x000 if I'm starting with a Morden or Ropstein genesis file, slightly modified for my own use?

Comment: It's hex number, 0x0 should work, but the bomb kicks in very late, so basically an low number should do.