# Correlation between network difficulty and total hash rate

Tags: hashrate, difficulty

I am expecting a linear relationship between difficulty and hash rate. If I generate a scatter plot between the two variables I can see a linear relationship, but also values that are not on the line (in red frame of figure). I tried to correlate this with protocol changes, but this was not successful. Why are this values of the line?

[image]

The data is borrowed from https://etherscan.io/charts
The information about the forks I have found here: http://list.wiki/Ethereum_Forks

You can find the code to generate the plot in https://gist.github.com/Slebi/1e1e614dcccc7e04424da5126c80c0a6

Answer (score 2):

Without looking in too much detail, I'm going to speculate that it's due to the difficulty adjustments related to the originally planned Difficulty Bomb. (See: [What is the "difficulty bomb" and what is the goal of it?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/323/what-is-the-difficulty-bomb-and-what-is-the-goal-of-it?rq=1))

The EtherScan [chart](https://etherscan.io/chart/blocktime) to look at would be the one showing how the block time increased in a series of steps (due to the increased difficulty), up until the point of the Difficulty Bomb's cancellation ([EIP-649](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/669)), which is when it shifted back to your yellow path.

[image]