# What is the Muir Glacier hardfork?

Tags: hardforks, forks, difficulty, difficulty-bomb, muir-glacier

What is the Muir Glacier hardfork on the Ethereum mainnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Muir Glacier fork is a hard fork of the Ethereum network that delays the [difficulty bomb](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/323/what-is-the-difficulty-bomb-and-what-is-the-goal-of-it). The fork is expected to happen on block 9,200,000 in January 2020 and will contain a single EIP, [EIP 2387](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2387).

This fork delays the difficulty bomb 4 million blocks.